# How to concatenate two strings and search for them within my React JSX in Next.js? And How to make file (MDX JS) content searchable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concatenation, next.js, mdxjs

I have the following function where I am trying to search the 'title' and 'summary' for something entered in the search bar. However, this throws an error that 'const' is not allowed here.

```
import { frontMatter as blogs1 } from './blog/*.mdx';
const filteredBlogPosts = blogs1
    .sort(
      (a, b) =>
        Number(new Date(b.publishedAt)) - Number(new Date(a.publishedAt))
    )
    .filter((frontMatter) =>
      const concat = frontMatter.summary + frontMatter.title, #Error. How to search for both title and summary for entered search value?
      concat.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()),
    );
```

The blogs1 that gets imported has content like this - how do I make the content part of the MDX file searchable as well? At least with title and summary, I have a key-value pair. But how to make text in content of this MDX file (anything after 'Table of Contents' in example below) searchable too?

```
---
title: 'abc def ghi'
publishedAt: '2020-09-06'
summary: "xyz mnk."
image: '/static/images/chapter18/1.png'
---

## Table of Contents

1.  [Introduction](#introduction)
2.  [Alphabet and xyz](#comparing-alphabet-and-xyz)
3.  [ABC](#abc)

# Introduction

This is an attempt at something.<br/>

![Test](/static/images/chapter18/2.png)<br/>
```

Comment: it's probably too late but there are curly brackets missing just before `const concat`

Comment: @revelt Thanks. How do I make text in content of this MDX file (anything after 'Table of Contents' in example below) searchable too?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to answer your question exactly because you're stuck in a path where you need to step backwards and consider the whole "architecture" side.

For search, I'd recommend to use [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/api/indexing.html), see this [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-search-to-a-react-app-with-fuse-js/).

I do have a search feature on my [website](https://codsen.com) and it is searching the MDX sources: articles and npm package readme's.

Conceptually, you have to make a script which `fs.readFileSync`-reads all MDX, extracts the JSON-like "list" (from fuse.js terminology) and writes it into a file (I make it `.ts`). Then, React app imports it and runs the fuse client-side.

In npm scripts, in package.json, we end up with two scripts, instead of `"build": "next build"`, you prepend the search index generation script, something like: `"build": "node './ops/generate.mjs' && next build"`.

I even published my "list" fuse string generation function as an npm package, see [extract-search-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-search-index). It takes a string, article's source, which you get by `fs.fileReadSync` and then slice from the second instance of `---`, that's just under the front-matter.

I estimate the total "weight" of the search feature ends up around 200KB, but it's loaded in async then cached; Remix manages it well.